# Refresh Control not working on Android -React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, pull-to-refresh

Here is My Code

```
        <FlatList
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                    enabled={true}
                    refreshing={loader}
                    onRefresh={() => getLockerHistory(1)}
                    tintColor={ThemeColors.primary}
                />
            }
            ListEmptyComponent={noDataMessage()}
            onScroll={(e) => {
                if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
                    return;
                }
                let paddingToBottom = 20;
                paddingToBottom += e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
                if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >= e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height - paddingToBottom) {
                    getNextRecordsPage();
                }
            }}
            ListFooterComponent={() => {
                return (
                    <ActivityIndicator color={ThemeColors.black} animating={footerLoader} />
                );
            }}
            ListFooterComponentStyle={footerLoader ? { marginVertical: 20 } : {}}
            ListFooterComponentStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}
            onEndReached={() => {
                if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
                    getNextRecordsPage()
                }
            }}
            onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 0 : null}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.lockerCode + '' + index}
            data={lockers}
            renderItem={(itemData) => {
                return renderItem(itemData.item, props.navigation);
            }}
        />
```

When I have more then 5 records which means there is not empty space left on screen then the refresh control won't work. It only works the seperator space between cells.
And my cell is made up of plain views nothing fancy or touchable.

***Note: I tried to debug it with empty view but seems like pull/drag to refresh is not being listen by Flat List.***

Any help?

Comment: I changed the flatlist import from react-native-geatures to react-native. And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me to achieve Refresh Control

```
import { View, Text, RefreshControl, FlatList } from 'react-native'

<FlatList
          testID="DiscussionView"
          initialNumToRender={5}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
          windowSize={11}
          data={posts}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={this.onRefresh} />}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          renderItem={this.renderPostItem}
          onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
          scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
          contentContainerStyle
          listKey="DiscussionViewList"
          onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
            this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false
          }}
        />

onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      { refreshing: true },
      // Do what you want,
    )
  }

keyExtractor = (item) => String(item.id)

renderPostItem = ({ item }) => {
    // Render Item here
}

onEndReached = () => {
    if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
      // Call API again if needed by use case
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true
    }
}
```